# Is it possible to add a description on the bottom of a carousel slider on a SharePoint modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

I am using a modern SharePoint page and I have added a carousel slider using a highlighted content web part, but not sure how to add a description to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no OOB way to add description using highlighted content web part with carousel slider.

You could add your own idea via [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/).